# unable to get the connection Id after connecting the signalR in angular with asp net core

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, signalr-hub

In my application I have wrote the code for connecting the signalR with angular in dotnet core on server side.

But after connecting to signalR in angular I am unable to get the connectionId from hubconenction.

here is my code.

**.service.ts**

````
private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection

initWebSocket() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://localhost:5000/chat',{
        
      })
      .build();
  
      this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))

  
  this.hubConnection.on('recieveMessage', (data: any) => {  
    console.log("connectionId is" + data.connectionId) 
    
  });  

     ```

In the above console I have to get the connection Id from the connection but I am unable to get the connection
Can anyone help me on the same
````